# Evaluating A Path Integral In Polar Coordinates

Tags: integration

Show that the path integral of $f(x,y)$ along a path given in polar coordinates by $r=r(\theta)$ where $\theta_1 ≤ \theta ≤ \theta_2$, is

$$\int_{\theta_1}^{\theta_2} f(r \cos \theta ,r \sin \theta) \sqrt {r^2+(\frac{dr}{d\theta})^2 } d\theta$$

I thought $x = r \cos \theta, y = r \sin \theta$

So  $r(\theta)=(r\cos(\theta), r\sin(\theta))$, 
$\int_{\theta_1}^{\theta_2}f(r(\theta))||r'(\theta)||d\theta$

Then $\int_{\theta_1}^{\theta_2} f(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)\sqrt {r^2}d\theta$, ($\frac{dr}{d\theta})^2$ do not appear in the square root.

I cannot understand what happens. I think polar coordinates is something to do with it.

Comment: You have a bit troubles with your notation. You are missing that $r$ can depend on $\theta$.

Comment: @Fabian I now thoroughly understand what I misunderstood!!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hints**

1) The path integral of the scalar field $f(\bf{x})$ on a curve $C$ with parametric equation ${\bf{x}}={\bf{x}}(t)$ is defined as

$$I = \int\limits_C {f({\bf{x}}(t))\left\| {{{d{\bf{x}}} \over {dt}}(t)} \right\|dt} $$

2) In your example, we can find that

$$\eqalign{
  & \theta  \equiv t  \cr 
  & {\bf{x}} = r(\theta ){\bf{r}}(\theta )  \cr 
  & {{d{\bf{x}}} \over {d\theta }} = {{dr} \over {d\theta }}(\theta ){\bf{r}}(\theta ) + r(\theta ){{d{\bf{r}}} \over {d\theta }}(\theta ){\mkern 1mu}   \cr 
  & {\mkern 1mu} {\mkern 1mu} {\mkern 1mu} {\mkern 1mu} \,\,\,\,\,\, = {{dr} \over {d\theta }}(\theta ){\bf{r}}(\theta ) + r(\theta ) \pmb{\theta} (\theta )  \cr 
  & \left\| {{{d{\bf{x}}} \over {d\theta }}} \right\| = \sqrt {{r^2}(\theta ) + {{\left( {{{dr} \over {d\theta }}} \right)}^2}(\theta )}  \cr} $$

Comment: What r(θ)θ(θ) means?

Comment: @JAEMTO: Look at the answer again! I suceeded to write it in bold case! :)

Comment: I wanted to write the first $\theta$ as bold to express it is a vector but I couldn't! In fact $\frac{{d{\bf{r}}}}{{d\theta }}\left( \theta  \right) = \pmb{\theta} (\theta )$.

Comment: I am now confused r$(\theta)$ :what is bold and not. What it means is the bold and not bold exactly?

Comment: @JAEMTO:  $\bf{r}$ and $\pmb{\theta}$ are unit vectors in polar coordinates. :)

Comment: @JAEMTO: The bold case letters are vectors while the not bolds are just scalars. :) Can you understand this equation ${\bf{x}} = r(\theta ){\bf{r}}(\theta )$?

Comment: Am I right?

I mean like, xy-coordinates: there exists a path c:I= [a,b] -> lR^2(x(t),y(t))

In this problem, a path θ:=[θ 1,θ 2] ->(r(θ),θ (θ)) (1,2: subscript)

Then, is that right r(θ)=rcosθ, θ(θ)=rsinθ?

Comment: And I'm wondering where rcosθ,rsinθ goes. We don't need it??

Comment: I didn't understand  x=r(θ)r(θ), I thought I understood, but I read it again, I don't. Could you explain it please?

Comment: @JAEMTO: I think you have some problems with the concept of parametric equations of a curve. In your example the parametric equations of the curve whose parameter is $\theta$ can be written in Cartesian coordinates as
$${\bf{x}} = r(\theta )\cos (\theta ){\bf{i}} + r(\theta )\cos (\theta ){\bf{j}}$$
Or in polar coordinates as
$${\bf{x}} = r(\theta ){\bf{r}}\left( \theta  \right)$$
where
$${\bf{r}}(\theta ) = \cos (\theta ){\bf{i}} + \sin (\theta ){\bf{j}}$$

Comment: ${\bf{x}} = r(\theta )\cos (\theta ){\bf{i}} + r(\theta )\cos (\theta ){\bf{j}}
?$ isn't it  $ {\bf{x}} = r(\theta )\cos (\theta ){\bf{i}} + r(\theta )\sin (\theta ){\bf{j}}$? Now I can see what it means.

Comment: @JAEMTO: Yes, That was a Typo! Happy you finally got it! :)

Answer (score 1):

First note that Polar Coordinates are orthogonal coordinates, so the unit vectors $\mathbf{\hat r}$ and $\mathbf{\hat \theta}$ are orthogonal.

Now, from  a point $P=(r, \theta)$ a displacement given by an infinitesimal change in coordinates $(dr,d\theta)$ is a segment whose length can be found using the pythagorean formula. The displacement in the direction of $\mathbf{\hat r}$ is obviously $dr$ and the displacement in the direction of $\mathbf{\hat \theta}$ is $rd\theta$ ( as you can easily see thinking that $d\theta$ is an infinitesimal angle) , so we have:

$$
ds=\sqrt{dr^2 +r^2d\theta^2}=d\theta \sqrt{\left(\frac{dr}{d\theta}\right)^2 +r^2}
$$

Answer (score 1):

First equation is correct. It can be written also with respect to arc length.

$$\int_{\theta_1}^{\theta_2} f(r,\theta) \sqrt {r^2+(\frac{dr}{d\theta})^2 } d\theta$$
$$\int_{s_1}^{s_2} f(r,\theta)\,  ds $$

$$\int_{x_1}^{x_2} g(x,y) \sqrt {1+(\frac{dy}{dx})^2 } dx $$
$$\int_{s_1}^{s_2} g(x,y)  \,  ds $$

Comment: What is the g then?
You mean xy-coordinate?

Comment: No harm using the same f label or g.  $ f( r \cos \theta , \theta) = g( x, tan^{-1}\frac {y}{x}) $
.